# Oracle Forms 11g compilation errors

Tags: oracle, compilation, oracleforms

I was recently required to take over a project which was built on Oracle Forms 11g.

I checked out the source code and tried to compile fmb files, but I received a large number of comile errors, below are some typical errors for examples

identifier 'TO_MESSAGES.MODULE' must be declared
identifiter 'TO_MESSAGES.MESSAGE' must be declared

Oralce developer in my company suggest these errors maybe related into incorrect Oracle Forms installation and some missing core libraries. I tried to re-install all required software, but the errors are still there. I am new to Oracle Forms development, could anyone point me to right direction ?

Here is information about my local environment and tools
Windows 7 Enterprise 64 -bit
Oracle Portal, Forms, Reports and Discoverer 11g (11.1.1.2.0) for Microsoft Windows x86 (64-bit)
Oracle Portal, Forms, Reports and Discoverer 11g Patch Set 3 (11.1.1.4.0) for Microsoft Windows x86 (64-bit)
Oracle Form Builder 11.2.0.4.0
Java version "1.6.0_45"
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0

Answer (score 0):

By looking the above errors it does not seems to related to Oracle forms installation. I think these are functions and procedures which have been declared in plsql libraries created by developers and these libraries are not attached to the form.

Check for the .pll files in your source code and try to attach to the form and compile after that and then it should be compiled.